# como retornar el ID seleccionado del DropDownList, web form en C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webforms

Hola como andan? disculpen que los moleste.
estoy realizando una web form con c# en asp.net y implemente un DropDawnList en el archivo .aspx y en el archivo con el mismo nombre aspx.cs lo recibo y siempre es el mismo ID

así lo tengo en el .aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList class="form-control m-2" ID="ddlMarca" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

de esta forma lo recibo en el aspx.cs

```
modelo.IDMarca = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMarca.SelectedValue);
```

en el html aparecen bien

```
    <option value="1">BMW</option>
    <option value="2">Yamaha</option>
    <option value="3">Ford</option>
```

también probé con SelectedIndex, SelectedItem.value y nada siempre retorna 1

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 ¿Intentaste algo?

Comment: que te retorna cuando usas el selectedItem.value??

Comment: Hola como andas? siempre me retorna un 1

Comment: En que parte lo estas llenado? en el load? este inconveniente suele suceder cuando se vuelve a llenar el DropDown y entonces por defecto sin querer se selecciona el primer registro

Comment: Hola si si al DropDown  lo completo en el Page_Load